# How to remove part and section numbers from titles

Tags: sectioning

Using XeLaTeX and Book package.

I'd like to remove "part #" and "section #" from the \part and \section titles, thus keeping the part and section titles only. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the class `book` has no leading section for `\section`. I suppose you mean "chapter".

Comment: If you want that *no* sectional unit is numbered, then say `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` before `\begin{document}`. Otherwise, please state better your problem. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Since you have a response below that seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). If it does not answer your question, feel free to add some more information.

Answer (score 11):

> Confer the [Wikibooks article on Section numbering](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Section_numbering):

“To get an unnumbered section heading which does not go into the Table of Contents, follow the command name with an asterisk before the opening curly brace:
`\subsection*{Introduction}`. […] If you want the unnumbered section to be in the table of contents anyway, use the `\addcontentsline` command like this:

```
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
```

[…]”

> For more info (PDF bookmarks for the unnumbered chapters, clearing the page after `\chapter`s) please see the Wikibooks article.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, to *suppress in the **whole document*** parts and chapters names and/or numbers (like **Part I**, and **Chapter 2**) is to actually change it to nothing on the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\partname}{}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

#### NOTE:

If you are a `babel` or `polyglossia` user the above code is useless for the `\partname` and similars, instead you'd have to use:

```
\addto\captionsLANGUAGE{\renewcommand{\partname}{}
                        \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}} 
\renewcommand{\thepart}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```